# Why not call method from child adapter?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I use data binding.

Here parent adapter:

```
public abstract class PreviewSortAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter {
    protected Context context;

    @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String imageUrl) {
        Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(imageUrl)
                .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(
                        new GlideRoundedCornersTransformation(view.getContext(), (int) AndroidUtil.dpToPx(view.getContext(),
                                view.getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.image_rounded_corner_radius_dp)),
                                0, GlideRoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP)))
                .into(view);
    }

}
```

Here my child adapter:

```
public class MapListSortAdapter extends PreviewSortAdapter {
    public MapListSortAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<Merchant> data) {
        super(context, data, true);
    }

    @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String imageUrl) {
        Debug.d(TAG, "loadImage: ");
        Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(imageUrl)
                .into(view);
    }

@Override
protected int getLayoutForPosition(int position) {
    return R.layout.map_list_item;
}
}
```

As you can see in my child adapter I override method `loadImage()`. I want to call method `loadImage()` from child adapter.

Herer **map_list_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.myproject.android.customer.api.model.Merchant" />

    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:minHeight="90dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:imageUrl="@{item.preview.formats.reference.url}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

As you can see I use custom tag `app:imageUrl` to call method `loadImage()`.
The problem is that method is call but it call of parent adapter - `PreviewSortAdapter.loadImage()`.

But I need to call this method in child adapter: `MapListSortAdapter.loadImage()`.

Answer (score 1):

Methods anotated with the **static** modifier doesn't have hieritance. Just remove the static modifier and it should work

Comment: Is in data binding I can use NON static method to call from xml?  Here official example from Google:   `BindingAdapter({"bind:imageUrl", "bind:error"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String url, Drawable error) {
   Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(url).error(error).into(view); `
}

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can call any method of the variables that you pass inside <data></data> in your xml

Comment: You are getting this error because you are trying to call a non static method without the instance of an object of the class. Try to pass an object with the method that you need (loadImage()).

Comment: In xml: `app:loadImage="@{(item) -> clickHandler.loadImageRounded(item)}"`  But I get error: `@BindingAdapter loadImageRounded(com.myproject.android.customer.api.model.Offer) has 1 attributes and 0 value parameters. There should be 1 or 2 value parameters.
     public void loadImageRounded(Offer offer) {`

Comment: If you use a non-static BindingAdapter, you must supply a `DataBindingComponent`. For example, use `DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent()`. It is used to tell data binding which instance to use with your binding calls.